# How to find the capacity of a collection in DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on an aplication where I insert documents into documentdb and I'd like to know How to determine how much space is left in a DocumentDB collection using the Java API?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Java person myself, but in .NET lingo the code to do it is:

```
var task = DocClient.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(myCollection.SelfLink);
task.Wait();
var response = t.Result; 
var totalQuota = response.CollectionSizeQuota;
var amountUsed = response.CollectionSizeUsage;
```

The response CollectionSizeQuota should be the usual 10G and the CollectionSizeUsage is how much you've used (in MB).

Pretty sure that the Java API's would be very similar.